# Bootstrap, jquery, ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, file-organization

Recently I have been getting a few errors that hadnt appeared before for the files described not being found? It causes my cards to not go to their full size but works properly in the atom html preview.
[image of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WnuC.png)

I will list a section of my code as im unsure if it is from the script order being incorrect or an incorrect version or something along those lines, thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Please add a code section to your question

Answer (score 2):

Open your website via http:// and it most likely will work

Accessing external files are not permitted if the website is opened locally as file://

Answer (score 0):

Since you are opening the file locally and not by using a web server, you are not allowed to use any external resources unless they are hosted in your PC.

If you are using Google Chrome and you want to use CDN's, you can install a plugin which will turn your browser to a web server, so you can include external files as you wish.

[Use this link to go to the chrome web store, where you can find that addon.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)